# How can I add webscraped html data to dataframe having multiple values in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am learning Python and trying to create a DataFrame with Pandas. I want to take the data from the table from this website https://www.chilli-diy.com/chilikeimtabelle/ so I can later on visualize it with altair. I am having troubles with the column "Schärfe" because there are multiple values I guess (1-10, 1 bis 4, 10+,...) 
So all I get is the "Brazilian Ghost", because it has no value?
thanks in advance

```
permalink = ('https://www.chilli-diy.com/chilikeimtabelle/')
chilis = requests.get(permalink).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(chilis, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all('table')
names = []
peps = []
for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        if(peps is None):
            continue
peps.append(cells[2].text)
names.append(cells[0].text)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Chilisorte" : names, "Schärfe" : peps })
df

Out:

    Chilisorte  Schärfe
0   Brazilian Ghost
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF4e5.png)

Comment: Please consider sharing your code here.

Comment: Hey, if you click on the output link you can see a screenshot. Sorry for the mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the DOM of the page in your browser, you'll see that all Chilisorte column cells (`<td>`) have classes *column-1*, and Schärfe column table cells have classes *column-3*.

The easiest way would be to extract all cells with relevant classes into 2 list, extract their `.text` value, and add into a dataframe.

```py
permalink = ('https://www.chilli-diy.com/chilikeimtabelle/')
chilis = requests.get(permalink).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(chilis, "html.parser")

col1_tds = tables[0].findAll('td', {"class": "column-1"})
col1 = [ td.text for td in col1_tds ]

col3_tds = tables[0].findAll('td', {"class": "column-3"})
col3 = [ td.text for td in col3_tds ]

pd.DataFrame({
    "Chilisorte": col1,
    "Schärfe": col3
})
```

Output:

```
    Chilisorte  Schärfe
0   Anaheim     1 bis 4
1   Habanero Chocolate  10
2   Habanero White  10
3   Bird Pepper Wild    9
4   Bhut(Bih) Jolokia Yellow    10+
...     ...     ...
272     Naglah  10++
273     Dorset Naga     10+++
274     Jigsaw  10+++
275     Black Naga  10+
276     Brazilian Ghost     

277 rows × 2 columns
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dataframe is empty because `names` and `peps` are appended outside of the loop. So all they have in is the last element. Also, I guess, you you wanted to check if the `cell is None`, not `peps`

```
names = []
peps = []
for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        if cells:
            peps.append(cells[2].text)
            names.append(cells[0].text)
```